# Android: Trying to get rid of Material support toolbar background

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design

Just below the toolbar, there is a black bar which is the 'include' tag. Any idea on how to get rid of it?

[image]

My common base theme between multiple apps (values/styles.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CommonBaseTheme.Base.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CommonBaseTheme.Light" parent="CommonBaseTheme.Base.Light"></style>

    <style name="CommonBaseTheme.Base.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CommonBaseTheme.Dark" parent="CommonBaseTheme.Base.Dark">    </style>
</resources>
```

My common Material base theme between multiple apps (values-v21/styles.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="CommonBaseTheme.Light" parent="CommonBaseTheme.Base.Light">
        <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CommonBaseTheme.Dark" parent="CommonBaseTheme.Base.Dark">
        <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And then my app-specific one (values/styles.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Runewords.Base" parent="CommonBaseTheme.Dark">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <!-- The theme to use in app -->
    <style name="Theme.Runewords" parent="Theme.Runewords.Base"></style>
</resources>
```

The activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activity.RecipeActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/include4"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutWebview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        <!-- ... -->
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally, toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

Please let me know if I'm missing any details. I have a feeling it's a minor mistake.

Comment: change the theme in Android Studio build system to you self-defined theme. in your image, it's the button with name "Dark" on the left of "Recipe" button. click that and change to your theme and see if it helps

Comment: Ahh thanks that helped, now it's no longer showing the original toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You are including two action bars. One is the support Toolbar via XML and the other is included via your theme. You probably want to be using a theme without action bar.

```
<style name="CommonBaseTheme.Base.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    ....
</style>
```

Comment: this is equivalent to "<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>"

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam That's correct. See also: https://gist.github.com/kerukerupappa/6159846

Comment: FYI, the full version should be ```<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>```
to fully support old version. If you see the source code of ```.NoActionBar```, they include those lines too (if I'm not wrong)

Answer (score 0):

There were a few problems with this.

- @ahorner was right, I had two bars (one with the theme, one from the include)
- @Nguyễn Hoài Nam was also right, I also had the editor on the wrong theme
- Problem was I had the "include" tag with the ID of "@+id/include4" and the toolbar in toolbar.xml with id "@+id/toolbar", where it should have been the "include" named "@+id/toolbar"

I also cleaned up `CommonBaseTheme.Base.*` to use the NoActionBar equivelants to keep things clean.